# Анимация рисунка

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте.! Можете, пожалуйста, помочь сделать так, чтобы нарисованный фрагмент на рисунке двигался? А именно: скейтер на стену, а то я не могу понять как это сделать. Вроде через массивы надо, но я не понимаю как.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);


    gr.DrawEllipse(p, 47, 120, 20, 20);// голова
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(57, 185), new Point(57, 140));// тело
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(80, 160), new Point(57, 148));// рука 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(57, 148), new Point(35, 160));// рука 2
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(80, 207), new Point(57, 185));// нога 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(57, 185), new Point(35, 207));//нога 2

    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(25, 207), new Point(90, 207));// доска
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 30, 207, 12, 12);// колесо 1
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 73, 207, 12, 12);// колесо 2
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 34, 210, 4, 4);// болт 1
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Red, 77, 210, 4, 4);//болт 2
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(20, 200), new Point(25, 205));// грань 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(88, 207), new Point(98, 200));// грань 2

    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(-10, 218), new Point(1000, 218));// земля
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(380, 218), new Point(380, 130));// стена 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(390, 130), new Point(390, 218));//стена 2
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(390, 131), new Point(380, 131));//стена 3
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(380, 180), new Point(350, 155));// шип 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(349, 155), new Point(380, 150));// шип 2

    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, 6, 40, 60, 20);// облако 1
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, 50, 70, 40, 20);//облако 2
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, 150, 45, 40, 40);// солнце
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, 200, 60, 50, 25);// облако 3
    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, 70, 35, 60, 20);// облако 4


    gr.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, 300, 30, 40, 40);// шар
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(300, 55), new Point(315, 90));// стропа 1
    gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(325, 90), new Point(339, 55));//стропа 2
    gr.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 308, 90, 25, 20);// корзина
}
```

Comment: Зачем такие извращения, не проще в фотошопе нарисовать спрайт и передвигать его как объект?

Comment: Данный ресурс не предназначен для решения студенческих задач. Мы помогаем людям учиться, но не решаем за них задачи. В Вашем коде нет и намёка на динамичность, а лишь статический рисунок. Вы хотите, чтобы за Вас сделали всю задачу. Вы ошиблись сайтом.

Comment: я не хочу чтобы за меня все сделали, а показали только как делать, я понимаю и воспринимаю информацию только когда вижу ее

Comment: Вам объяснили как сделать. Просто сделайте отрисовку частей, которые нужно анимировать зависимыми от неких переменных. К примеру:  `gr.DrawLine(p, new Point(x1, y1), new Point(x2, y2));// земля` и меняйте их согласно правилу анимации, которую вы хотите получить. Ну и по таймеру отрисовывайте картинку. Вот и вся анимация.

Answer (score 1):

- Раздели рисование объектов по функциям (человечек, скейт, земля, небо, воздушный шар)
- Добавь таймер и запускай его по клику на кнопке (`button1_Click`)
- Делай отрисовку по событиям от таймера
- Статичные объекты рисуй всегда на одном и том же месте, а динамичным меняй положение каждый кадр - получишь анимацию

Comment: а можете пожалуйста пример показать, что бы я точно поняла?

Comment: Заметил что у тебя все в `button1_Click` сделано - тут очень большой пример надо делать. А что, уроки/пары прогуливала?

Comment: не прогуливала, я просто гуманитарий, и нам такое задали) да клише прям

Comment: значит с кнопки лучше все вытащить?